# Best Linear Unbiased Estimator (BLUE) in the context of Data Assimilation Models - Can you help show me this?

Tags: statistical-inference, least-squares, estimation

I am reading the following book: Data Assimilation: Methods, Algorithms, and Applications (https://epubs-siam-org.iclibezp1.cc.ic.ac.uk/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611974546) and they have mentioned BLUE and I understand the general idea and proofs available here, as related to the Guass-Markov Theorem ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem#:~:text=In%20statistics%2C%20the%20Gauss%E2%80%93Markov,have%20equal%20variances%20and%20expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20statistics%2C%20the%20Gauss%E2%80%93Markov,have%20equal%20variances%20and%20expectation)).

I am however having one issue in that I cannot see how they have arrived at the equation for $\hat{B}= (K^TC_N^{-1}K)^{-1}K^TC_N^{-1}$ in **Theorem 3.27**. When I try and solve such a problem I get the OLS solution, which is given in **Remark 3.28**, $\hat{x}_{BLUE} = (K^TK)^{-1}K^Tz$.

Would someone be so kind as to tell me/give me a hint on how they have arrived at $\hat{B}$? Image of the page in question is given below.

Thanks all!

[image]

Comment: I didn't look at the material, but isn't $C$ here a weight matrix? So if you get the OLS solution you assume $I$ as the weights/no correlation from the start?

Comment: @Dole When I consider the OLS solution I solve by minimising the squared error $|| C_N ||^2$ which would be $||Kx - z ||^2$ as shown in 3.28. What I do not see is how in the general case, 3.27, that $C_N^{-1}$ is part of the solution for $\hat{B}$

Comment: @Dole Sorry, $C_N^{-1}$ is not a weight matrix it is actually the covariance matrix for the random variable N. See my updated question

Comment: Yes, so it appears you have assumed uncorrelatedness, which is a Gauss-Markov assumption IIRC, that is not assumed here. Then you need the extra multiplication with the inverse...

Comment: @Dole That is indeed a Gauss-Markov Assumption! Would you mind then showing how I would go about starting to solve this to get the form presented for $\hat{B}$? Specifically what I mean is, how does the extra multiplication with the inverse appear? Where does it arise from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gauss-Markov theorem gives the BLUE estimator when:

- The expectation of errors is zero.
- The covariance of errors is zero.
- The errors have finite variance.

The theorem proven does not assume the covariance of errors is zero, as is stated in the remark this case can be obtained by selecting $C=I\sigma^2$ as the correlation matrix. In the case where errors are correlated OLS is NOT BLUE, and we use a different estimator. We can describe the model as follows

$$y=X\beta+C^{1/2}\epsilon,$$

where $C$ is the covariance matrix and $\epsilon$ are uncorrelated. Hence:

$$\Leftrightarrow C^{-1/2}y=C^{-1/2}X\beta+\epsilon,$$

And now we have a model with uncorrelated errors, running OLS with respect to it is BLUE, in particular by minimizing the sum squares we get
$$\hat \beta = ((C^{-1/2}X)'(C^{-1/2}X))^{-1}(C^{-1/2}X)'C^{-1/2}y$$

$$=(X'C^{-1}X)^{-1}X'C^{-1}y$$

Which is what the theorem shows is BLUE (not OLS), as should be.

Comment: Thanks so much for this!

Comment: How does pre-multiplication of $\epsilon$ by the matrix $C^{\frac{1}{2}}$ introduce correlation between the errors? I understand the math from that point onwards but would appreciate if you could explain how that specifically implies uncorrelatedness?

Comment: The $\epsilon$ here is a vector of $n$ observations, and $C$ a square matrix, just computing should make it clear. Recall also $Var(A\epsilon)=A^2Var(\epsilon)$, where $Var$ gives the covariance matrix.

Comment: $\epsilon$ is a vector of random noise correct? Sometimes drawn from $N(0, I)$. Pre-multiplication by a square matrix $C$ would give a transformed vector of the same dimension as $y$. I still don't see how we now have correlation? Typically, I have seen in the past that samples of $\epsilon$ are drawn $i.i.d$ from whatever distribution we sample the noise from. What am I missing then?

Comment: Because the vector has past observations of $\epsilon$. E.g. we may have $\epsilon_i+\epsilon_{i-1}$ as the vector, then it is correlated.

Comment: I see. That was my misunderstanding. I thought every entry of $\epsilon$ would hold a new entry of error at time $t$.